# Number of permutations with a restriction on cycle length

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of permutations of length n if no cycle can exceed a maximum length $m$, where $m \lt n$?

Comment: Using exponential generating functions we have that the generating function of these permutations is given by
$$ G(z) = \exp\left( \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{z^k}{k} \right) =
\exp\left( \log \frac{1}{1-z} -\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k} \right) =
\frac{1}{1-z} \exp\left(-\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k}  \right).$$
It follows that the value we are looking for is given by
$$ n! [z^n] G(z) = n! \sum_{q=0}^n [z^q] 
\exp\left(-\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k}  \right).$$
This expression can be simplified for $m$ fixed.

Comment: Here are some relevant sequences from the OEIS: [m=2](http://oeis.org/A000085), [m=3](http://oeis.org/A057693) and [m=4](http://oeis.org/A070945).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel, please make this comment(s) into an answer.